# How do I properly cut a chicken breast into strips or chunks?

Tags: chicken, knife-skills, chicken-breast, cutting, knife-safety

I often cut fresh chicken breasts into strips for stir-fry or similar uses. What type of knife should I use and how should I cut it? I'm not trying to debone as I buy boneless cuts already.  I'm most interested in the techniques associated with efficiency and safety.

Some related questions that don't address my question specifically:

- [How do I cut out the vein/tendon from a chicken breast tendorloin?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24854/how-do-i-cut-out-the-vein-tendon-from-a-chicken-breast-tendorloin)
- [Is it generally better to cut chicken breast with or against the grain?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-it-generally-better-to-cut-chicken-breast-with-or-against-the-grain)

Comment: fwiw I splurged on a good deboning knife and I use it for cutting any kind of meat   very sharp and more precise than a chef's knife.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non serrated **sharp** knife.

I prefer using a chef knife, about 10in long.

Cut the breast length wise to make slices, and after that, cut each slice into strips.

If wanting to make "chunks", then cut each strip into cubes.

Depending on the recipe, you can vary the thickness of each slice/strip/cube.

Comment: +1 for _non-serrated sharp knife_.  Any reasonable long knife will do.  But the key to slicing raw meat cleanly and efficiently is a very sharp knife.  Try doing it with a knife that's dull or one of those cheap knifes with the small serrations, and you'll just be tearing and squishing the meat all over the place.  Sharp knives are also much safer here, because you'll be less tempted to use more force and frantic sawing motions out of frustration with a dull blade.